# For loop looping one too many times

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have some code:

```
var cart = [];
var items = [];
var cart_node = document.querySelectorAll('#tblItineraryModuleStayDetail > tbody > tr');
var cart_as_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(cart_node, 2); // start at item 3 (2)
for(var i=0;i<cart_as_array.length;i+=2) {
    items.push(cart_as_array[i]);
}
```

Now, in the console if I type items I get:

[image]

So I expect the loop to go around once in this instance.

Here's my loop:

```
for(i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    // set vars
    cart[i] = {};
    var name = items[i].querySelector('.txtStayRoomDescription').textContent;
    var price = items[i].querySelector('.tblItinPriceSummary tr td:last-child').textContent;
    var brand = items[i].querySelector('.txtStayRoomLocation').textContent;

    // add to object
    cart[i].name = name;
    cart[i].price = price;
    cart[i].brand = brand;

    // add to cart array
    cart.push(cart[i]);
  }
```

Which gives:

[image]

I expected a result with array cart containing one item object not two. But it has two identical objects.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At line 3 of your code you create an empty object in your array:

```
cart[i] = {};
```

then at line 14 you push that object into your array *again*:

```
cart.push(cart[i]);
```

You should instead just create an object, and push it at the end:

```
var item = {};
// ... add properties to item ...
cart.push(item)
```

Comment: Ah I see now. Thanks for spelling it out.

Answer (score 3):

You're first setting the ith element of the `cart` array as your object, then also pushing it onto the end; this will put two copies in, as you see.

Edit for question in comments:

Let's go through your code line by line:

```
for(i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    // set vars
    cart[i] = {};
```

After `cart[i] = {}` puts an empty object in the `cart` array at index `i`; if there was something there before, it will be overwritten, otherwise the array will simply be added.

```
// stuff setting properties removed

// add to object
cart[i].name = name;
cart[i].price = price;
cart[i].brand = brand;
```

Now, the object at `cart[i]` has received the attributes you constructed. The `cart` array now contains an object with these name, price, and brand attributes at position `i`.

```
// add to cart array
cart.push(cart[i]);
```

Now, in addition to the reference at `i`, you've pushed a second reference to the object stored at `i` on to the end of the array. This will produce the behavior you are observing: the object will be in the array twice.

I would recommend changing `cart[i] = {}` (and the associated code that adds properties of this object) to construct the object while it is stored in a local variable, then push it on to the array at the end of the loop.

Comment: Actually, they're not copies. They both refer to the same object.

Comment: I'm sorry this must look really obvious to folk who have seen this post. I'm not following though

Comment: @Barmar: yes, copies is sloppy here; I should have said two references

Comment: @DougFirr: `cart[i] = {}` assigns the object to index `i` of `cart` (index `0` in your example) but then `cart.push(cart[i])` appends the same object to the same array, so now it's held at index `1` as well.